# How to save the contents of a tableviewer into a text file in swt

Tags: java, swt, rcp, e4, tableviewer

I have created a table viewer and displaying the contents in the table.Now i have created a button called save which has to  save all the contents of the table into a file .I have created a dialog window to give the file name but i am not getting how to save the complete data in the table to a text file.So how can we save the complete data in the table to text file .The code for dialogbox is as follows

```
Button btnSave= new Button(topComposite, SWT.BUTTON2);
        btnSave.setText("Save");
        //btnSave.addSelectionListener(new OpenFiler());



        btnSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e){
                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.SAVE);
                dialog.setText("Save");
                String[] filterExt = { "*.log" };
                dialog.setFilterNames(filterExt);
                String absolutePath = dialog.open();
                if (absolutePath == null)
                    return;
                                dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.log" });                                                           dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\"); // Windows path
                        }
        });
```

Please help me how can we save the complete data in the table to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. `viewer` is the instance of your table viewer. Add this code at the end of the `addSelectionListener` method of button `btnSave`.

```
    TableItem[] items = viewer.getTable().getItems();
    File fl = new File(dialog.getFilterPath() + File.separator + dialog.getFileName());
    FileWriter flwr;
    int cls = viewer.getTable().getColumnCount();
            try {
                flwr = new FileWriter(fl);
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= cls; j++) {
                        flwr.write(items[i].getText(j) + "\t");
                    }
                    flwr.write("\n");
                }
                flwr.flush();
                flwr.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```